# How to use XDocument class in Mono

Tags: c#, linq, mono, unity-game-engine, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to use `XDocument` class inside a `Unity3D` project on `Windows 7`.

I did the following:

- added the reference `System.Xml.Linq` to the Mono project.
- included the namespace:

  ```
  using System.Xml.Linq;
  ```
- set the target framework to: `Mono/.NET 3.5`
- clean and rebuild the project

But still `Unity3D` complains about it. Here's the error output in the console:

> Assets/Scripts/Editor/RoadManager/RoadManager.cs(3,18): error CS0234:
>   The type or namespace name `Linq' does not exist in the namespace
>   `System.Xml'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Any idea?

Comment: Oops I overlooked this - answer deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912432/unity3d-and-system-xml-linq) [many](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/86428-Can-t-find-System.Linq.Xml) [times](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/210822/problem-with-systemxmllinq.html?sort=oldest) [before](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/46039/can-not-reference-systemxmllinq.html), but few of these answers are complete.

As has been said before, Unity3d only supports up to .NET version 2.0, and it seems System.Xml.Linq was introduced in .NET 3.5, besides the fact that it is not listed on the [Unity3d compatibility list](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html) anywhere.

<s>The only things to try are to set the Mono API compatibility level to 2.0 (Menu: Edit > Project Settings > Player and look in the Other Settings panel), but it seems that that was a mistaken solution for Linq2SQL.</s>

Another possible solution is to add the DLL yourself into the Unity Editor as shown:

> Try dragging the C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll file
>   into the unity project window like you would a texture or other game
>   asset.

If none of these yield ANY luck for you, then **I'm afraid you are out of luck.**

Comment: Yes. I added the .dll shipped with Unity3D by my self and it works. Even without pro release.

Answer (score 1):

Unity3D supports .Net 2.0 only, so setting compatibility to .net 3.5 in MonoDevelop/Visual Studio will not work. You will have to make do without the class. This shows what library classes are available:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html

See also this post in UnityAnswers: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/46039/can-not-reference-systemxmllinq.html